# ngTable custom header is not working with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

When I use the `ng-if="Event.EventItem.IsShirtsEnabled"` on the custom header then header is not working for any value of the above condition.That means, it is hidden all the time.But body part is working fine with the above condition.Could you tell me why ? Thanks in advance.

[ngTable](http://ng-table.com/#/demo/5-8)

```
<table ng-table="ParticipantsParams" class="table" template-pagination="custom/pager">
        <thead>
           <tr>
      //here it's not working
           <th ng-if="Event.EventItem.IsShirtsEnabled" class="sortable" ng-class="{'sort-asc': ParticipantsParams.isSortBy('ShirtSize', 'asc'),'sort-desc': ParticipantsParams.isSortBy('ShirtSize', 'desc')}"
        ng-click="ParticipantsParams.sorting({'ShirtSize' : ParticipantsParams.isSortBy('ShirtSize', 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc'})" rowspan="2">
                 <div>Shirt Size</div>
                   </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="item in Event.Participants">
        <td data-title="'Shirt Size'" ng-if="Event.EventItem.IsShirtsEnabled" sortable="'ShirtSize'">{{item.ShirtSize}}</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```